# Is there value in having both [reentrant] and [reentrancy]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I can't see any reason why we would have both [reentrant](/questions/tagged/reentrant) (33 questions) and [reentrancy](/questions/tagged/reentrancy) (58 questions). I would have thought them to be equivalent, but I lack specific knowledge on the point; there may be some subtle value in the distinction.

Are they OK as they are (well, there'd still be a problem in that case—clarification would be needed), or should they be merged, or should one be marked a synonym of the other?

Comment: I tried adding a tag synonym, but I couldn't because of "something score 5 something something"

Comment: @Dariusz: which way would you suggest taking it? (viz., which do you reckon should be the tag and which the synonym?)

Comment: Reentrancy, noun and a general term; adjective says nothing